# PDCurses Win32a build with mingw

Tags: c, windows, mingw, pdcurses

I try to build PDCurses using MinGW, but have a problem in the second file which is specific for win32a:

```
..PDCurses-master\win32a>mingw32-make -f mingwin32.mak WIDE=Y UTF8=Y

...
gcc -c -O4 -Wall -I.. -DPDC_WIDE -DPDC_FORCE_UTF8 ../pdcurses/window.c
gcc -c -O4 -Wall -I.. -DPDC_WIDE -DPDC_FORCE_UTF8 ../pdcurses/debug.c
gcc -c -O4 -Wall -I.. -DPDC_WIDE -DPDC_FORCE_UTF8 ../win32a/pdcclip.c
gcc -c -O4 -Wall -I.. -DPDC_WIDE -DPDC_FORCE_UTF8 ../win32a/pdcdisp.c
../win32a/pdcdisp.c:451:1: error: unknown type name 'GLYPHSET'
 GLYPHSET *PDC_unicode_range_data = NULL;
 ^
```

And some other errors in lines 450 - 470. 
I have already reinstall MinGW, but the problem is the same. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The GLYPHSET structure is defined in wingdi.h. Perhaps you did not include windows.h ?

Comment: It is really strange, but this file includes windows.h...

Comment: you couid do a word search for GLYPHSET in the include files directory to find out in which header file it is defined and then include it